# Why does, in python, Stack's pop method and Queue's dequeue method behave differently when both have same code?

Tags: python, data-structures, stack, queue

When the `pop()` method of a list is used in class `Stack`, it returns the last element of the list (head of the stack) while in class `Queue` it returns the 1st element. Can anybody explain me the reason behind this?

```
# coding: utf-8

class Queue (object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.items.insert(0,item)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

class Stack(object):    
    def__init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

q = Queue()
q.enqueue(1)
q.enqueue(2)
q.enqueue(3)
q.enqueue(4)
q.enqueue(5)
q.enqueue(6)

s = Stack()
s.push(1)
s.push(2)
s.push(3)
s.push(4)
s.push(5)
s.push(6)

q.dequeue() #Output: 1

s.pop() #Output: 6
```

Comment: Because `Queue.enqueue` is adding to the start of the list, and `Stack.push` is adding to the end.

Comment: Have you tried to actually read the code? There are some not very subtle difference in how the nodes are *added* to the list.

Answer (score 1):

> When the `pop()` method of a list is used *[...]* in class `Queue` it returns the 1st element.

No, it does not. It still returns the last element of the list. You should not look at `dequeue` and `pop`, you should instead concentrate on the `Queue.enqueue` and `Stack.push` methods.

The `Stack` class **appends** to the `items` list, so puts the new element at the end:

```
def push(self, item):
    self.items.append(item)
```

while the `Queue` **inserts** at the *start* of the `items` list:

```
def enqueue(self, item):
    self.items.insert(0,item)
```

So when you pop from the stack, you remove the element that was *last* added. When you pop from the queue, you remove the element that was *first* added, as everything else was inserted in front  of it.

Put differently, the `Queue` hold items in chronological order (newest item is at the start of the list), while the `Stack` holds them in reverse chronological order (newest item is at the end of the list). Popping still removes the last element from the list.